# Affect the class used to called a function

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm wondering if there's a way I can make a function that will affect the class which calls it. For example, below the 'change text' function will change the text of instance 'testing' of my class, but I was wondering if there is a way of setting it so that rather than being specifically testing.label['text'], the 'testing' can be changed to a keyword which will reference whatever instance of a class was used to call the function.

```
root = Tk()

def change_text:
    testing.label['text'] = "New Text"

class MyGui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        master.geometry("250x100") 
        master.wm_title("Register App")

        self.label = Label(frame, text="Original Text", fg="Black")
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

        self.changeButton = Button(frame, text="Change Text", command=change_text)
        self.changeButton.grid(row = 2, column = 2)


testing = MyGui(root)
testing
```

So, if I haven't been clear, I'd like to make a function that if called by say an instance of a different class, 'MyGui2', it will manipulate its .label function.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot define `change_text` as `change_text(obj)` and then work on that?

Comment: Or, as a method of MyGui, which accepts `self`, and you can change `self.label`?

Comment: Could you explain a bit further bit?

Comment: Yes Daniel, I'm trying to avoid referencing it within the class itself

Comment: Well, it's hard to explain without showing all the code, but basically there would be multiple GUI instances of all different forms which need text manipulated, and rather than copying a function into each one of them I'd rather have a common one that all can reference externally

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "called by"? The code you've shown never calls `change_text`, so there's nothing to work on.

Comment: Your example never calls `change_text`. Are you calling it via a binding? A button? Something else?

Comment: Good point, my bad - my actual code does but this was just an example. I'll edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Object Orientation](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/); a base class with a common method can help you here:

```
    class BaseGui(object):
        def change_text(self, newText):
            self.label['text'] = newText

    class MyGui(BaseGui):
        ...

    testing = MyGui(root)
    testing.change_text('New text')
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Not exactly what I was looking for but it will do the job just fine - I was aware of these but it didn't cross my mind to do that